# How to select all factor variables in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame named "insurance" with both numerical and factor variables. How can I select all factor variables so that I can check the levels of the categorical variables?

I tried `sapply(insurance,class)` to get the the classes of all variables. But then I can't make logical argument based on if `class(var)="factor"` as the variable names are also included in the result of `sapply()`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some data:

```
insurance <- data.frame(
  int   = 1:5,
  fact1 = letters[1:5],
  fact2 = factor(1:5),
  fact3 = LETTERS[3:7]
)
```

I would use `sapply` like you did, but combined with `is.factor` to return a logical vector:

```
is.fact <- sapply(insurance, is.factor)
#   int fact1 fact2 fact3 
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Then use `[` to extract these columns:

```
factors.df <- insurance[, is.fact]
#   fact1 fact2 fact3
# 1     a     1     C
# 2     b     2     D
# 3     c     3     E
# 4     d     4     F
# 5     e     5     G
```

Finally, to get the levels, use `lapply`:

```
lapply(factors.df, levels)
# $fact1
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
# 
# $fact2
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
# 
# $fact3
# [1] "C" "D" "E" "F" "G"
```

You might also find `str(insurance)` interesting as a short summary.

Answer (score 2):

This (almost) appears the perfect time to use the seldom-used function rapply

```
rapply(insurance, class = "factor", f = levels, how = "list")
```

Or

```
Filter(Negate(is.null),rapply(insurance, class = "factor", f = levels, how = "list"))
```

To remove the `NULL` elements (that weren't factors)

Or simply

```
lapply(Filter(is.factor,insurance), levels))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
insurance %>% select_if(~class(.) == 'factor')
```

Comment: Hi there - this may solve the OP's problem, but it would be more useful if it said **why** it solves the OP's problem. Explanations help people learn :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use dplyr and purrr here. First select the factor columns and then use purrr::map to show the factor levels for each column.

```
library(tidyverse)

insurance %>%
  select(where(is.factor)) %>%
  map(levels)
```

Answer (score -2):

using the data frame "insurance" from flodel to get all the factors in one go, you can use `apply` , like so:

```
apply(insurance,2,factor)

     int fact1 fact2 fact3
[1,] "1" "a"   "1"   "C"  
[2,] "2" "b"   "2"   "D"  
[3,] "3" "c"   "3"   "E"  
[4,] "4" "d"   "4"   "F"  
[5,] "5" "e"   "5"   "G"
```

if you are interest only in the levels of one factor you can do the following:

```
factor(insurance$fact1)

[1] a b c d e
Levels: a b c d e
```

Comment: I wasn't the first downvote, but the reason for adding negativity is to discourage you from using `apply` when it is not appropriate. It coerces its first argument to a matrix, a character matrix here. The factor information is lost.

Comment: DWin, thanks for leaving a comment with the downvote. I was not aware of the problem `apply` might cause using it the way I suggested.I would encourage everyone to add a short comment when downvoting rather than "just do it", it's not personal after all and thoughtful comments can add as much knowledge to the community as correct answers.