# finding out all levels in factor variable

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Using the famous 'adults' dataset from the UCI machine learning repository ([here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/adult))

dataset look like this:

```
    Observations: 32,561
Variables: 15
$ AGE           <int> 39, 50, 38, 53, 28, 37, 49, 52, 31, 42, 37, 30, 23, 32, 40, 34, 25, 32, 38, 43, 40, 54, 35, 43, 59, ...
$ WORKCLASS     <chr> "State-gov", "Self-emp-not-inc", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Self-emp-no...
$ FNLWGT        <int> 77516, 83311, 215646, 234721, 338409, 284582, 160187, 209642, 45781, 159449, 280464, 141297, 122272,...
$ EDUCATION     <chr> "Bachelors", "Bachelors", "HS-grad", "11th", "Bachelors", "Masters", "9th", "HS-grad", "Masters", "B...
$ EDUCATIONNUM  <int> 13, 13, 9, 7, 13, 14, 5, 9, 14, 13, 10, 13, 13, 12, 11, 4, 9, 9, 7, 14, 16, 9, 5, 7, 9, 13, 9, 10, 9...
$ MARITALSTATUS <chr> "Never-married", "Married-civ-spouse", "Divorced", "Married-civ-spouse", "Married-civ-spouse", "Marr...
$ OCCUPATION    <chr> "Adm-clerical", "Exec-managerial", "Handlers-cleaners", "Handlers-cleaners", "Prof-specialty", "Exec...
$ RELATIONSHIP  <chr> "Not-in-family", "Husband", "Not-in-family", "Husband", "Wife", "Wife", "Not-in-family", "Husband", ...
$ RACE          <chr> "White", "White", "White", "Black", "Black", "White", "Black", "White", "White", "White", "Black", "...
$ SEX           <chr> "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Mal...
$ CAPITALGAIN   <int> 2174, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14084, 5178, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
$ CAPITALLOSS   <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2042, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1...
$ HOURSPERWEEK  <int> 40, 13, 40, 40, 40, 40, 16, 45, 50, 40, 80, 40, 30, 50, 40, 45, 35, 40, 50, 45, 60, 20, 40, 40, 40, ...
$ NATIVECOUNTRY <chr> "United-States", "United-States", "United-States", "United-States", "Cuba", "United-States", "Jamaic...
$ ABOVE50K      <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
```

I changed all variable of class character into factor using:

```
df <- df %>% mutate_if(is_character, as.factor)
```

Now I like to see the level of each factor variable, I could do this:

```
levels(df2$working_class)
levels(df2$education)
levels(df2$marital_status)
```

And so on for each factor variable.  Surely, there should be an easier way to do this with the purrr package.  Something like:

```
df %>% map_if(is.factor, levels)
```

Unfortunately, this chooses everything even the columns of class integer.

How should I make map works for it to consider only the factor variables and return their levels?
Thanks

Comment: As an update: I found this to work:  df %>% select_if(is.factor) %>% map_if(is.factor, levels).   No I do not understand why that works but not these df2 %>% select_if(is.factor) %>% map(is.factor, levels) or df %>% map_if(is.factor, levels)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help==

```
 library(df)
 df %>% select_if(is.factor) %>% 
 sapply(levels)
```

Comment: Thanks.  It is better output than df %>% map_if(is.factor, levels), but it still return levels for each variables instead of just the variables of type factor.  This would be better:  df %>% select_if(is.factor) %>% sapply(levels)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907944/how-to-select-all-factor-variables-in-r